# Javascript re-write of js/php music composition program

Tags: php, javascript

A while ago, I created (with much help) a program that uses php and javascript to make some ambient music by randomizing an array of `.ogg` files. Now I am trying to re-write it with js alone.

The new code immediately below does *not* work (the `.ogg` files do play properly when clicked individually, but nothing happens when you press the 'start' button, which is the main feature). (The code below that (containing php) *does* work.) I've been over the new code several times and I think I've got the 'typos'. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the syntax of the window.setTimeout line, but haven't quite figured out how it should be.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Audio Testing</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function getRandInt (min, max) 
        {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

    function shuffle(o) 
        {
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
        }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var tonesTotal = 150;  

    function getDelays(tonesTotal)   
        {
            var return_array = array();
            for (var i = 0; i < tonesTotal; i++)
                {
                    var r = getRandInt(0, 600);    
                    var delay = r * 1000;
                    return_array.push(delay);  
                }
            return return_array;  
        }

    var delays = new Array();
    delays = getDelays(tonesTotal);

    $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $("#start").click(function()     
                {   
                var base = 'sound';
                for(var i = 0; i < tonesTotal; i++)
                    var id = base + ((i + 1) ); 
                    window.setTimeout ("document.getElementById('" + id + "').play()", delays[i]);

                });
        }); 

</script>
</head> 

<body style="background-color: #999;">

    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <br><br>

<script> 
    var tonesTotal = 150; 
    var samples = new Array("tone0.ogg", "tone2.ogg", "tone4.ogg", "tone6.ogg", "tone7.ogg", "tone9.ogg", "tone11.ogg", "tone12.ogg");  
    for (var i=1; i <= tonesTotal; i++) 
    {
        shuffle (samples);
        var samplepick = samples[0];
        document.write ("<audio controls id='sound" + i + "'><source src='" + samplepick + "' type='audio/ogg'></audio>");
    }               
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PREVIOUS CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Audio Testing</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php 
    //$randC = rand(1,4); 
    $C = 150;

    function getDelays($C)
    {
        $return_array = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < $C; $i++)
        {
            $r = rand(0, 600);
            $delay = $r * 1000;
            array_push($return_array, $delay);
        }
        return $return_array;
    }
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
    echo "var delays = new Array();";
    $delays = getDelays($C);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($delays); $i++)
    {
        echo "delays[" . $i . "] = " . $delays[$i] . ";\n";
    }
    echo "
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
              $(\"#start\").click(function() 
              { 
                var base = 'sound';
                for(i = 0; i < $C; i++)
                {           
                    var id = base + ((i + 1) ); 
                    window.setTimeout (\"document.getElementById('\" + id + \"').play()\", delays[i]);
                }
              });             
            });
        </script>
        ";
        ?>

        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
</head> 

<body style="background-color: #999;">

    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <br><br>

    <?php
    $samples = array("tone0.ogg", "tone2.ogg", "tone4.ogg", "tone6.ogg", "tone7.ogg", "tone9.ogg", "tone11.ogg", "tone12.ogg"); 
    for ($i=1; $i<= $C; $i++) {
        shuffle ($samples);
        $samplepick = $samples[0];
        echo '<audio controls id="sound'.$i.'">
        <source src='.$samplepick.' type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>';
    }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't really a helpful description. What exactly behaves differently from the way you want it? Do you see any errors in the error console?

Comment: good point, I clarified it: when you press the 'start' button, nothing happens. As I am new, I am unfamiliar with the error console but I will look into it.

Comment: Do you mind posting the server address so that the audio files can load? I can't really test my solution without them

Comment: alas, I've got it running locally. but I'd be super happy to to drop/zip/send them. OR, it should work with any group of files that play in html5 audio... it just won't sound 'ambient'. (It'll sound like Charles Ives!)

Comment: Ok, just getting stuck with the delay code, give me a bit

Comment: no prob thanks for checking it out!

Comment: Got it to work, but it doesn't continue to loop. From the original version, can you explain the following values: `$C = 150;` & `var riff_time = 2920;` I don't understand why 150, and I can't see where `riff_time` is used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36590/discussion-between-gregory-tippett-and-graham-walters)

Comment: for future reference: `var riff_time` served no function, and was left over evolutionarily like the human appendix. I removed it so as to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested it locally I found a Javascript error in the getDelays() function: First line of code should be:

```
var return_array = new Array();
```

Comment: or even `var return_array = [];`